# Collecting text inputted information and posting it to a php document. Using method get

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have been editing survey code not originally mine, I have been editing it so I can use it for my research and I am having an issue with recording age and code input and posting it to my save_results.php. Here is where I call on HTML. These are ust snippets of the code as the code itself is rather extensive.

```
      function showNext() {
    if (currSlide == 1) {
      var d = new Date();
      startTime = d.getTime();

      document.getElementById("Next").style.position="absolute";
      document.getElementById("slide0").style.display = "none";

      var ex = document.getElementById("code_input");
      ex.style.left = string_l + "px";
      ex.style.top = string_t;
      ex.style.display = "block";
      currSlide++;



     } else if (currSlide == 2) {
     var code_val = $(document.getElementById("code_input"))
     var code = document.getElementById("CodeID").value;
     if (code.length == 0) {
     promptNonresponse();

     } else {

      document.getElementById("slide0").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("code_input").style.display = "none";

      var ex = document.getElementById("age_input");
      ex.style.left = string_l + "px";
      ex.style.top = string_t;
      ex.style.display = "block";
      currSlide++;
      }

      } else if (currSlide == 3) {
       var age_val = $(document.getElementById("age_input"))
       var age = document.getElementById("AgeID").value;
       if (age.length == 0) {

       promptNonresponse();}

     }
```

Here is the HTML for the age and code.

```
   </script>

   <div class="input-group" id="code_input" method="get" display="none">
    <form>
    <span class="slideText">Please enter a word that you will remember in 
     case you wish to withdraw your data from this study.</span>
    <input type="text" id="CodeID" name="code" class="form-control" 
   placeholder="..." size="10"><br><br>
   </form>
   </div>


  <div class="input-group" id="age_input" method="get" display="none">
    <form>
   <span class="slideText">Please state your age</span>
     <input type="text" id="AgeID" name="age" class="form-control" 
     placeholder="Age" size="10"><br><br>

   </form>
   </div>
```

Below is the array for all the answers

```
       var answer = [document.getElementById("nomem").value,document.getElementById("code").value,document.getElementById("age").value,nodes[0].q1,(nodes.length > 1) ? nodes[1].name : "", (nodes.length > 1) ? nodes[1].q2 : "",(nodes.length > 1) ? nodes[1].friendsWith : "",(nodes.length > 2) ? nodes[2].name : "",(nodes.length > 2) ? nodes[2].q2 : "",(nodes.length > 2) ? nodes[2].friendsWith : "",(nodes.length > 3) ? nodes[3].name : "",(nodes.length > 3) ? nodes[3].q2 : "",(nodes.length > 3) ? nodes[3].friendsWith : "",(nodes.length > 4) ? nodes[4].name : "",(nodes.length > 4) ? nodes[4].q2 : "",(nodes.length > 4) ? nodes[4].friendsWith : "",(nodes.length > 5) ? nodes[5].name : "",(nodes.length > 5) ? nodes[5].q2 : "",(nodes.length > 5) ? nodes[5].friendsWith : "",(nodes.length > 6) ? nodes[6].name : "",(nodes.length > 6) ? nodes[6].q2 : "",(nodes.length > 6) ? nodes[6].friendsWith : "",(nodes.length > 7) ? nodes[7].name : "",(nodes.length > 7) ? nodes[7].q2 : "",(nodes.length > 7) ? nodes[7].friendsWith : "",(nodes.length > 8) ? nodes[8].name : "",(nodes.length > 8) ? nodes[8].q2 : "",(nodes.length > 8) ? nodes[8].friendsWith : "",(nodes.length > 9) ? nodes[9].name : "",(nodes.length > 9) ? nodes[9].q2 : "",(nodes.length > 9) ? nodes[9].friendsWith : "",(nodes.length > 10) ? nodes[10].name : "",(nodes.length > 10) ? nodes[10].q2 : "",(nodes.length > 10) ? nodes[10].friendsWith : "",(nodes.length > 11) ? nodes[11].name : "",(nodes.length > 11) ? nodes[11].q2 : "",(nodes.length > 11) ? nodes[11].friendsWith : "",(nodes.length > 12) ? nodes[12].name : "",(nodes.length > 12) ? nodes[12].q2 : "",(nodes.length > 12) ? nodes[12].friendsWith : "",(nodes.length > 13) ? nodes[13].name : "",(nodes.length > 13) ? nodes[13].q2 : "",(nodes.length > 13) ? nodes[13].friendsWith : "",(nodes.length > 14) ? nodes[14].name : "",(nodes.length > 14) ? nodes[14].q2 : "",(nodes.length > 14) ? nodes[14].friendsWith : "",(nodes.length > 15) ? nodes[15].name : "",(nodes.length > 15) ? nodes[15].q2 : "",(nodes.length>15)?nodes[15].friendsWith:"",nodes[0].q5,nodes[0].q6,nodes[0].q7,nodes[0].q8,nodes[0].q9,nodes[0].q10,nodes[0].q11,nodes[0].q12,nodes[0].q13,nodes[0].q14,nodes[0].q15,nodes[0].q16,nodes[0].q17,nodes[0].q18,nodes[0].q19,nodes[0].q20,nodes[0].q21,nodes[0].q22,nodes[0].q23,nodes[0].q24,nodes[0].q25,nodes[0].q26,nodes[0].q27,nodes[0].q28,nodes[0].q29,nodes[0].q30,nodes[0].q31,nodes[0].q32,nodes[0].q33,nodes[0].q34,nodes[0].q35,nodes[0].q36,nodes[0].q37,nodes[0].q38,nodes[0].q39,nodes[0].q40];

        console.log(answer)

        window.addEventListener("load", e => {
        document.getElementById("qu1_id").value = answer.join(",");
      })


        //Post collected data to handler for recording
        $.post( "save_results.php", {
        nomem: document.getElementById("nomem").value,
        code: document.getElementById("code").value,
        age: document.getElementById("age").value,
        q1: nodes[0].q1,
        q2_1: (nodes.length > 1) ? nodes[1].name : "",
        q3_1: (nodes.length > 1) ? nodes[1].q2 : "",
        q4_1: (nodes.length > 1) ? nodes[1].friendsWith : "",
        q2_2: (nodes.length > 2) ? nodes[2].name : "",
        q3_2: (nodes.length > 2) ? nodes[2].q2 : "",
        q4_2: (nodes.length > 2) ? nodes[2].friendsWith : "",
        q2_3: (nodes.length > 3) ? nodes[3].name : "",
        q3_3: (nodes.length > 3) ? nodes[3].q2 : "",
        q4_3: (nodes.length > 3) ? nodes[3].friendsWith : "",
        q2_4: (nodes.length > 4) ? nodes[4].name : "",
        q3_4: (nodes.length > 4) ? nodes[4].q2 : "",
        q4_4: (nodes.length > 4) ? nodes[4].friendsWith : "",
        q2_5: (nodes.length > 5) ? nodes[5].name : "",
        q3_5: (nodes.length > 5) ? nodes[5].q2 : "",
        q4_5: (nodes.length > 5) ? nodes[5].friendsWith : "",
        q2_6: (nodes.length > 6) ? nodes[6].name : "",
        q3_6: (nodes.length > 6) ? nodes[6].q2 : "",
        q4_6: (nodes.length > 6) ? nodes[6].friendsWith : "",
        q2_7: (nodes.length > 7) ? nodes[7].name : "",
        q3_7: (nodes.length > 7) ? nodes[7].q2 : "",
        q4_7: (nodes.length > 7) ? nodes[7].friendsWith : "",
        q2_8: (nodes.length > 8) ? nodes[8].name : "",
        q3_8: (nodes.length > 8) ? nodes[8].q2 : "",
        q4_8: (nodes.length > 8) ? nodes[8].friendsWith : "",
        q2_9: (nodes.length > 9) ? nodes[9].name : "",
        q3_9: (nodes.length > 9) ? nodes[9].q2 : "",
        q4_9: (nodes.length > 9) ? nodes[9].friendsWith : "",
        q2_10: (nodes.length > 10) ? nodes[10].name : "",
        q3_10: (nodes.length > 10) ? nodes[10].q2 : "",
        q4_10: (nodes.length > 10) ? nodes[10].friendsWith : "",
        q2_11: (nodes.length > 11) ? nodes[11].name : "",
        q3_11: (nodes.length > 11) ? nodes[11].q2 : "",
        q4_11: (nodes.length > 11) ? nodes[11].friendsWith : "",
        q2_12: (nodes.length > 12) ? nodes[12].name : "",
        q3_12: (nodes.length > 12) ? nodes[12].q2 : "",
        q4_12: (nodes.length > 12) ? nodes[12].friendsWith : "",
        q2_13: (nodes.length > 13) ? nodes[13].name : "",
        q3_13: (nodes.length > 13) ? nodes[13].q2 : "",
        q4_13: (nodes.length > 13) ? nodes[13].friendsWith : "",
        q2_14: (nodes.length > 14) ? nodes[14].name : "",
        q3_14: (nodes.length > 14) ? nodes[14].q2 : "",
        q4_14: (nodes.length > 14) ? nodes[14].friendsWith : "",
        q2_15: (nodes.length > 15) ? nodes[15].name : "",
        q3_15: (nodes.length > 15) ? nodes[15].q2 : "",
        q4_15: (nodes.length > 15) ? nodes[15].friendsWith : "",
        q5: nodes[0].q5,
        q6: nodes[0].q6,
        q7: nodes[0].q7,
        q8: nodes[0].q8,
        q9: nodes[0].q9,
        q10: nodes[0].q10,
        q11: nodes[0].q11,
        q12: nodes[0].q12,
        q13: nodes[0].q13,
        q14: nodes[0].q14,
        q15: nodes[0].q15,
        q16: nodes[0].q16,
        q17: nodes[0].q17,
        q18: nodes[0].q18,
        q19: nodes[0].q19,
        q20: nodes[0].q20,
        q21: nodes[0].q21,
        q22: nodes[0].q22,
        q23: nodes[0].q23,
        q24: nodes[0].q24,
        q25: nodes[0].q25,
        q26: nodes[0].q26,
        q27: nodes[0].q27,
        q28: nodes[0].q28,
        q29: nodes[0].q29,
        q30: nodes[0].q30,
        q31: nodes[0].q31,
        q32: nodes[0].q32,
        q33: nodes[0].q33,
        q34: nodes[0].q34,
        q35: nodes[0].q35,
        q36: nodes[0].q36,
        q37: nodes[0].q37,
        q38: nodes[0].q38,
        q39: nodes[0].q39,
        q40: nodes[0].q40
        });

        checked = false


        var sf = document.getElementById("submitForm");
        var sb = document.getElementById("submitButton");
        var nd = document.getElementById("NextDiv");
        sf.style.display = "block";
        nd.style.display = "none";
        var motivationText = d3.select("svg").append("text")
          .attr("class", "slideText")
          .attr("id", "motivationText")
          .attr("x", center - (textWidth / 2) + 50)
          .attr("y", text_offset_top + 40)
          .text("Thank you for participating in this study. Click \"Next\" to end the survey.")
          .call(wrap, textWidth);

        // Release window close-prevention
        unhook();

      }
```

And here is the HTML submit form.

```
    <div id="submitForm">
  <form id="customapplication" action="<?php echo $_POST  ['returnpage']; ?>" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id= "code" name="code" value="<?php echo $_POST['code']; ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" id= "age" name="age" value="<?php echo $_POST['age']; ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="KeyValue" value="<?php echo $_POST['KeyValue']; ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="InterviewID" value="<?php echo $_POST['InterviewId']; ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="Lmr" value="<?php echo $_POST['Lmr']; ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $_POST['statusvarname1']; ?>" value="<?php echo $_POST['statusvarvalue1']; ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $_POST['varname1']; ?>" id="qu1_id" value=""/>
    <input type="hidden" id="nomem" name="nomem" value="<?php echo $_POST['nomem']; ?>"/>
    <input name="<?php echo $_POST['nextvarname']; ?>" id="submitButton" class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Next"/>
  </form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#Next").css("left",window.innerWidth * .8);
    $("#submitButton").css("left",window.innerWidth * .8);
</script>
```

And finally here is the save_results.php

```
     <?php

     $list = array (
      array(
  $_POST['nomem'],
  $_POST['code'],
  $_POST['age'],
  $_POST['q1'],
  $_POST['q2_1'],
  $_POST['q3_1'],
  $_POST['q4_1'],
  $_POST['q2_2'],
  $_POST['q3_2'],
  $_POST['q4_2'],
  $_POST['q2_3'],
  $_POST['q3_3'],
  $_POST['q4_3'],
  $_POST['q2_4'],
  $_POST['q3_4'],
  $_POST['q4_4'],
  $_POST['q2_5'],
  $_POST['q3_5'],
  $_POST['q4_5'],
  $_POST['q2_6'],
  $_POST['q3_6'],
  $_POST['q4_6'],
  $_POST['q2_7'],
  $_POST['q3_7'],
  $_POST['q4_7'],
  $_POST['q2_8'],
  $_POST['q3_8'],
  $_POST['q4_8'],
  $_POST['q2_9'],
  $_POST['q3_9'],
  $_POST['q4_9'],
  $_POST['q2_10'],
  $_POST['q3_10'],
  $_POST['q4_10'],
  $_POST['q2_11'],
  $_POST['q3_11'],
  $_POST['q4_11'],
  $_POST['q2_12'],
  $_POST['q3_12'],
  $_POST['q4_12'],
  $_POST['q2_13'],
  $_POST['q3_13'],
  $_POST['q4_13'],
  $_POST['q2_14'],
  $_POST['q3_14'],
  $_POST['q4_14'],
  $_POST['q2_15'],
  $_POST['q3_15'],
  $_POST['q4_15'],
  $_POST['q5'],
  $_POST['q7'],
  $_POST['q8'],
  $_POST['q9'],
  $_POST['q10'],
  $_POST['q11'],
  $_POST['q12'],
  $_POST['q13'],
  $_POST['q14'],
  $_POST['q15'],
  $_POST['q16'],
  $_POST['q17'],
  $_POST['q18'],
  $_POST['q19'],
  $_POST['q20'],
  $_POST['q21'],
  $_POST['q22'],
  $_POST['q23'],
  $_POST['q24'],
  $_POST['q25'],
  $_POST['q26'],
  $_POST['q27'],
  $_POST['q28'],
  $_POST['q29'],
  $_POST['q30'],
  $_POST['q31'],
  $_POST['q32'],
  $_POST['q33'],
  $_POST['q34'],
  $_POST['q35'],
  $_POST['q36'],
  $_POST['q37'],
  $_POST['q38'],
  $_POST['q39'],
  $_POST['q40'])
  );

 $fp = fopen('results/data.csv', 'a');

 foreach ($list as $fields) {
 fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

 fclose($fp);

?>
```

Apologies for the huge amounts of code I'm not sure exactly where I'm going wrong. And my knowledge of code is limited. For the most part I have being editing this code through trial and error. This seems to be the last hurdle so I'd be very grateful if anyone could give me a hand.

Comment: The method you are using in the sample code is POST not GET (in your save handler), but setting that aside, what is the problem you are having? The problem I see is that there is no connection between your form that is posting to the save handler and the data that is in your other forms. You either need to use one `<form>` to contain everything or you'll need to use javascript to move the values into hidden fields of the `<form>` that is actually posting to the handler.

Comment: I thought that too, but all my HTML used get method but somehow records the data and posts it to the save_results.php. The problem I am having is that when i log the answers (console.log(answers) all other fields record any data inputted and save to the results.php however the age and code results simply aren't being recorded, this is what I want to fix.

Comment: It's because you have those fields in a different `<form>` tag. When data posts, it only posts what is within the `<form>` tag of the submit button.

Comment: Apologies I understand what you are saying but how would I fix it? Is it a case of putting where I refer to code and age in the submit form into the age and code form instead?
Again I'm a bit of a novice so I apologise.

Comment: Can you fit all of the fields into one `<form>` tag? If you must have them in different `<form>` tags you're going to need javascript to move the values of the fields that are in different forms over to `<input type="hidden">` fields in your form that is actually posting. I can't provide a complete answer with just the snippets you have without taking some major guesses, so all I can offer is this advice.

Comment: Well, thank you anyway.